# Access form variables

Tags: c#, forms, object, properties

When using a basic form application in C# I am having trouble accessing the variabels within it.

So with in the form class I have

```
public partial class pingerform : Form 
{
  ..
  ..

  private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox2;

  public string textBox2Text
  {
      get { return textBox2.Text; }
      set { textBox2.Text = value; }
  }
```

And then in the main application I have

```
Application.Run(new pingerform());
...
...

pingerform.textBox2Text.text() = str;
```

but I am told that there is no object reference.

> Error 1
>   An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'pingerform.textBox2Text.get' C:\Users\aaron.street\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 11\Projects\PingDrop\PingDrop\Program.cs   54  21  PingDrop

So I thought I would make the pinger form class static but it wont let me do this?

> Error 1
>   Cannot create an instance of the static class
>   'PingDrop.pingerform' C:\Users\aaron.street\Documents\Visual Studio
>   11\Projects\PingDrop\PingDrop\Program.cs  21  29  PingDrop

How can I access the forms properties with out creating a specific instance of the form,

I have a background thread running that I want to update a text filed with in the form at regular intervals?

Cheers

Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no choice but to create new instance and either pass it as parameter to the thread, or store it as member of your main Program class.

Example for the second option:

```
private static pingerform myPingerform = null;
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    myPingerform = new pingerform();
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateTextBox));
    thread.Start();
    Application.Run(myPingerform);
}

private static void UpdateTextBox()
{
    while (true)
    {
        myPingerform.textBox2.Text = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

And don't forget to change the textbox to be `public`.

**Note**: this is simple working solution to the simple case of one background thread accessing the textbox. If you have more threads accessing it, **this will break**. For best practice methods that require some more work, please [read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx).

Comment: Would this be considered best practice, creating an explicit instance of a form. and is so why is the method used when creating a template from in visual Studio not to do so.

Comment: @DevilWAH it is an only practice possible (except in VB or other madness)

Comment: @wRAR why will it break? Care to explain please? It's one form and one background thread can't see any risk for conflicts if that's what you mean.

Comment: took me a moment to see what you meant by that code :) but yer see what your doing now. The way I am trying to do it is by creating separate threads from with in the form. It all works fine in a console interface and from waht I have just tested from your suggestions I think I am over the hill. Cheers

Comment: @ShadowWizard because you access GUI elements from a non-GUI thread. You also shouldn't suggest making control fields public and accessing unprotected global variables from different threads (even though it seems safe in this case). Also I don't know how exactly the form will break when accessed before the GUI loop but it certainly will.

Comment: @wRAR I never said it's *best practice* it's a simple working solution that fit inside simple application without more threads or complex logic. I tested it prior to posting and it's working fine.

Comment: @ShadowWizard SO is not a place for horrible and clearly forbidden solutions. We already have too many incompetent professional programmers.

Comment: what is wrong with having a non GUI thread write to / update a GUI variable? What issues will it cause ?

Comment: @wRAR if you can prove it's so horrible and forbidden I will delete it,  but personally can't see what's the big deal. Like I said - it's working and it's not breaking.

Comment: @ShadowWizard http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx Also, saying "this may be wrong as I didn't read the documentation but it works for me so it's OK" is a clear sign of incompetency which is so widespread now.

Comment: @wRAR **two or more threads accessing the same control** - that's not the case here.

Comment: I see where you coming from wRAR and yes if i wanted to be a professional programmer then there may be tidier solutions. However I am a net work engineer and as we say in networking. Theres no right or wrong just good and bad. and in this case this gets me up and running. Once I the logic in thsi form sorted I will come back to look at the "good" way to handle the interthread communication. :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access properties of an instance without creating that instance, it is nonsense (or VB which is the same). And you have already created the instance which you then passed to `Application.Run()`. And anyway you cannot do anything with your form after `Application.Run()` because it returns only when app exits. If you want to do anything with the form you need to do that in some other places. And of course you cannot make the form class static because you need to create instances.

If you need to do something with a form in another thread, you need to pass the form instance to the thread when you create it. Note though that direct messing with GUI elements from non-GUI threads is a bad idea, you should use `Control.BeginInvoke()`.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
pingerform myForm = new pingerform();    
Application.Run(myForm);
myForm.textBox2Text = "this is text";
```

Comment: The `Run()` method is blocking.

Comment: but right in the fact that at the heart of this I need to create a instance of my form. Also as the process to update the form is running in a seprerate thread, would it still be blocked? Not saying using Run is the way forward. But just wondering :)

Comment: @DevilWAH to run your application you must use `Run()` it's basic.